# How to run Gatling Quickstart Test Case

Tags: gradle, gatling, gradlew, scala-gatling

I am trying to run the [Quickstart](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/tutorials/quickstart/) example with Gatling Gradle plugin 3.5.0 and Gradle 6.0.

I have the following directory structure:

[image]

At the root, I run
`./gradlew gatlingRun-loadtests.BasicSimulation`, making sure the Quickstart Test case package is loadtests and the Class name is BasicSimulation and all I get is:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 309ms
4 actionable tasks: 4 up-to-date
```

or when hitting my endpoint:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
4 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

My endpoint is not reached by any Gatling request.

Any clue on how to get this Quickstart working on Gradle?

Comment: I think the older version of the gatling gradle plugin needs ```gatlingRun {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}``` in `build.gradle`. If this works I'll provide a full answer explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to run the Quickstart example with Gatling Gradle plugin 3.5.0

You're really looking for trouble using a version released almost 2 years ago.

As of now, the latest version of Gatling is 3.8.3 and the latest version of the plugin is 3.8.3.2.

We also maintain official sample projects, eg https://github.com/gatling/gatling-gradle-plugin-demo-scala/blob/main/build.gradle

You should definitely start from here, instead of fighting old versions that even core committers have lost track.

Comment: You're right. The quickstart works like heaven with the new plugin using gradle 7.